# Python - Stratified Sampling with MiniBatch k-means

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means, sampling

I'm trying to cluster about a million objects, that each have a varying length of datapoints, generally less than 100. The features would be the date of the observations and the ID value of each object(let's say runner's(name) and their times in different races). I want to run minibatch k-means on this data, but I also want the algorithm to take stratified samples based on a third feature, let's say the U.S. state that the runner is from. Is there a way to implement such sampling within the minibatchkmeans function?

If not, is there a way to take stratified samples and then pass them to the function somehow? I thought about this, but it seems that if I took stratified samples and passed them to the base k-means algorithm, I wouldn't be able to aggregate the samples together and get one label for each object. Any advice?